# mysql "paste" two results together (side by side)

Tags: mysql, sql

I want something like `paste` command in unix, it takes two files and prints first line, of first file, then separator, then first line from second file, then newline, then second line from first file separator second line from second file, etc.

So I want something like this in sql, take columns from two tables, output result, columns of first rows (as one row) from first and second table, then second rows from both tables etc. Without cross join stuff like first row from first table with second row from second table etc. Is this even possible? Very hard to search for this on the net...

EDIT:

```
Table 1:          Table 2:
column bla        column cla
a                 80
z                 7
f                 15
k

Expected result:
column bla, column cla
a, 80
z, 7
f, 15
k, NULL
```

Very simple :), except not at all...

EDIT2:
please no @variables

Comment: Do you expect single column in the result set?

Comment: Add sample table data, and the expected result.

Comment: It's possible using concat, and row number variables. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Edited. For use in some seriously fancy stuff later on. Mainly to make certain rows appear in fixed positions in parent select.

Comment: It's for "booking feature" certain items must appear in certain positions, if I can join with integers table like this, I can implement it in pure sql without various nasty code.

Comment: What's the expected result if you also add k to table 1?

Comment: Now that is a good question, would expect it to be left out of results as no matching thing in second one, or could be with null in second column.

Answer (score 1):

```
create table if not exists first_40482804 (
    bla varchar(50)
) ;

create table if not exists second_40482804 (
    cla int
) ;

truncate table first_40482804 ;
truncate table second_40482804 ;

insert into first_40482804 ( bla ) values ('a') ;
insert into first_40482804 ( bla ) values ('z') ;
insert into first_40482804 ( bla ) values ('f') ;

insert into second_40482804 ( cla ) values ( 80 ) ;
insert into second_40482804 ( cla ) values ( 7 ) ;
insert into second_40482804 ( cla ) values ( 15 ) ;

set @blaRow = 0 ;
set @claRow = 0 ;

select concat( `first`.bla,',',`second`.cla) paste from
(   
    select @blaRow:=@blaRow+1 `row` , bla from first_40482804
) `first`
left join 
(
    select @claRow:=@claRow+1 `row` , cla from second_40482804
) `second`
on `first`.`row` = `second`.`row`
```

-- results

```
paste
a,80
z,7
f,15
```

Comment: Now do this without vars and I'm sold! :)

Comment: In mysql to get row numbers you need vars. ... you could wrap it in a stored procedure.

Comment: I'll make up a stored procedure example.

Comment: I upvoted you for effort (thanks), but vars or procedures are not an option for me, at least not the one I wana take.

Comment: You need some method of determining the row numbers ... it's either a variable or adding a column to the tables in question. No way around it in mysql that I know of.

Comment: Well there of course there are id columns, but one can not make much assumptions about them, they are unrelated, can be noncsecutive, can have order criteria on other columns thus not even monotonically increasing. Yes I know that for "simple joins" you need column, but I have this eery feeling that one can achieve that result in some way, not using vars, proc, just I can't yet formulate it.

Comment: The approach by http://stackoverflow.com/users/4197505/thomas-g eliminates the need to initiate the vars in separate statements.

Answer (score 1):

There's no ROWNUMBER facility in MYSQL but you can mimick it like this :

```
SELECT t.*, 
       @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
  FROM YOUR_TABLE t, 
       (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
```

So you can make 2 queries returning the row number for each table:

```
SELECT bla, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
  FROM table_1 , (SELECT @rownum := 0) r1


SELECT bla, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
  FROM table_2 , (SELECT @rownum := 0) r2
```

And join them together on the row number

```
SELECT
    CONCAT( T1.bla,',',T2.cla) 
FROM
    (   SELECT bla, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
          FROM table_1 , (SELECT @rownum := 0) r1
    ) T1
INNER JOIN
    (       SELECT cla, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
      FROM table_2 , (SELECT @rownum := 0) r2     
    ) T2
    ON T1.rank = T2.rank
```

Of course with that `INNER join` to get the results your are expecting, I have guessed that you have the same number of rows in both tables, otherwise this has no sense to me.

---

Edit: I am a bit late as keith posted more or less the same approach

Answer (score 1):

```
create table if not exists first_40482804 (
    bla varchar(50)
) ;

create table if not exists second_40482804 (
    cla int
) ;

truncate table first_40482804 ;
truncate table second_40482804 ;

insert into first_40482804 ( bla ) values ('a') ;
insert into first_40482804 ( bla ) values ('z') ;
insert into first_40482804 ( bla ) values ('f') ;

insert into second_40482804 ( cla ) values ( 80 ) ;
insert into second_40482804 ( cla ) values ( 7 ) ;
insert into second_40482804 ( cla ) values ( 15 ) ;

DELIMITER ;;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS get_paste_stored_procedure ;;

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE get_paste_stored_procedure()
BEGIN

    set @blaRow = 0 ;
    set @claRow = 0 ;

    select concat( `first`.bla,',',`second`.cla) paste from
    (   
        select @blaRow:=@blaRow+1 `row` , bla from first_40482804
    ) `first`
    left join 
    (
        select @claRow:=@claRow+1 `row` , cla from second_40482804
    ) `second`
    on `first`.`row` = `second`.`row` ;

END;;
DELIMITER ;

call get_paste_stored_procedure() ;
```