# How do I combine two queries on the same table to get a single result set in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, union

I am not very good at sql but I am getting there. I have searched stackoverflow but I can't seem to find the solution and I hope someone out there can help me. I have a table (users) with data like the following. The book_id column is a key to another table that contains a book the user is subscribed to.

```
|--------|---------------------|------------------|
|   id   |      book_id        |       name       |
|--------|---------------------|------------------|
|   1    |         1           |        jim       |
|   2    |         1           |       joyce      |
|   3    |         1           |        mike      |
|   4    |         1           |       eleven     |
|   5    |         2           |        max       |
|   6    |         2           |       dustin     |
|   7    |         2           |       lucas      |
|--------|---------------------|------------------|
```

I have a function in my PHP code that returns two random users from a specific book id (either 1 or 2). Query one returns the result in column 1 and result two returns the results in column 2 like:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |        2         |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        jim          |       max        |
|       joyce         |     dustin       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

I have achieved this by running two separate queries as seen below. I want to know if it's possible to achieve this functionality with one query and how.

```
$random_users_with_book_id_1 = SELECT name FROM users WHERE book_id=1 LIMIT 2
$random_users_with_book_id_2 = SELECT name FROM users WHERE book_id=2 LIMIT 2
```

Again, I apologise if it's too specific. The query below has been closest to what I was trying to achieve.:

```
SELECT a.name AS book_id_1, b.name AS book_id_2   
FROM users a, users b 
WHERE a.book_id=1 AND b.book_id = 2
LIMIT 2
```

EDIT: I have created a fiddle to play around with his. I appreciate any help! Thank you!! http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7fcbca/1

Comment: You're not clear. Please try harder to explain how the result is a function of the input. You seem to want to pair up two columns side by side. (Probably just user gui formatting better done outside the DBMS.) Add a row number column to limited sorted restrictions of table1, join on row number equality, then select other columns. This *is* a faq--google more until you find an answer or answers to parts--you are not the 1st person to ask this. Beware: MySQL has no ROW_NUMBER or RANK, and reading & updating a variable in one SELECT statement *undefined*.

Comment: Thanks @philipxy. I agree, I need to explain this abit more and I have edited my question and included a fiddle for that. I have a function in my PHP code that requires a list of users that have both 1&2 as the n_id. In my PHP code, I call two different sql functions, one that gets users from n_id 1 and another that gets users from n_id 2. I thought there was a better more efficient way of getting both sets of users using one sql query. Is that possible? Am i missing something here? Again I am not very good at SQL. I will continue searching SO and Google. I'm sure the answer is somewhere there

Comment: PS Googling 'stackoverflow "mysql" put two columns side by side by row number' gives https://stackoverflow.com/q/40482804/3404097 & others but they use @n=@n+1. In MySQL to get row numbers soundly you must write a procedure that inserts incrementing a column number by looping. (You can google that separately.) The MySQL company Percona has shown that *the current code* for MySQL can use @n=@n+1 safely in a certain way using CASE but I don't have a link right now.  Keep searching.

Comment: Thanks @philipxy. I have edited my question and added more explanation. I figured it could have been misleading with the row numbers (interesting after reading the links). But it's a bit way over what I wanted to achieve. I hope the question explains things a bit more clearly now?

Comment: Yes, more clear. (If you can, keep improving--eg, don't rely on examples.) (If the numbers of readers & books aren't really hardwired be sure to say.)

Comment: Thanks @philipxy. Someone gave me a working solution below. Interesting use of UNION. It will take some getting used to. Thanks for the help. I will be sure to make my questions more clear in future :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is easy actually :)

you can use UNION like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
     (SELECT * FROM user WHERE n_id=1 LIMIT 2)
     UNION
     (SELECT * FROM user WHERE n_id=2 LIMIT 2)) 
 collection;
```

if you read this article about [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) you can use the () to group the individual queries and the apply the union in the middle. Without the parenthesis it would still LIMIT 2 and show only the two first. Ref. "To apply ORDER BY or LIMIT to an individual SELECT, place the clause inside the parentheses that enclose the SELECT:"

Comment: Works like a charm and +1 for including the documentation. It helped alot. Just one question, is "collection" meant to do something? I noticed the query doesn't work without it. And I noticed i can change it to anything and the query works. I guess it's supposed to be an alias?

Comment: thanks. no collection is just a name I chose, use anything you like. yes you need that in order to group the union results ;)

Comment: I am getting syntax error near `UNION`

Comment: what is the error you are getting @MijanurRahaman ?

Comment: It was just saying `syntax error near UNION` and my actual issue is posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74392882/how-to-fetch-datetime

Comment: there is no UNION command in that link

Answer (score 1):

If you want to combine the queries in MySQL, you can just use parentheses:

```
(SELECT name
 FROM users
 WHERE n_id = 1
 LIMIT 2
) UNION ALL
(SELECT name
 FROM users
 WHERE n_id = 2
 LIMIT 2
);
```

First, only use `UNION` if you specifically want to incur the overhead of removing duplicates.  Otherwise, use `UNION ALL`.

Second, this does not return *random* rows.  This returns *arbitrary* rows.  In many cases, this might be two rows near the beginning of the data.  If you want random rows, then use `ORDER BY rand()`:

```
(SELECT name
 FROM users
 WHERE n_id = 1
 ORDER by rand()
 LIMIT 2
) UNION ALL
(SELECT name
 FROM users
 WHERE n_id = 2
 ORDER BY rand()
 LIMIT 2
);
```

There are other methods that are more efficient, but this should be fine for up to a few thousand rows.

Comment: Great! This is helpful. And thanks for distinguishing between `UNION` and `UNION ALL`. If you wouldn't mind, could you explain what you meant about the overhead? Thanks.

Comment: @realnsleo . . . `UNION` is slower than `UNION ALL`.